# Run SQLite in sandboxed environment

Tags: c#, sqlite, sandbox

My goal is to allow SQLite access from a sandboxed Lua environment.
But in the example below, it is still possible to use `attach database` (and probably more unwanted actions).
Is there a way to run SQLite queries in a sandboxed environment on a predefined SQLite file

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");

SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");

m_dbConnection.Flags = SQLiteConnectionFlags.Default | SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoBindFunctions |
                        SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoConnectionPool | SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoCreateModule |
                        SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoLoadExtension | SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoExtensionFunctions;

m_dbConnection.Open();

string sql = "attach database 'contacts.db' as contacts;";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

m_dbConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the connection, `SQLiteConnection` has an `Authorize` event, which you can use to prevent databases from being attached:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
conn.Authorize += Conn_Authorize;

...

private static void Conn_Authorize(object sender, AuthorizerEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ActionCode == SQLiteAuthorizerActionCode.Attach)
    {
        e.ReturnCode = SQLiteAuthorizerReturnCode.Deny;
    }
    else
    {
        e.ReturnCode = SQLiteAuthorizerReturnCode.Ok;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any other sql statements that can be misused ?

Comment: Tactical answer: look at the possbile `SQLiteAuthorizerActionCode` values, as the SQLite team deemed those actions worth including in the `Authorize` event. You could also deny all _except_ the ones you want to expose.

Comment: I think i wil stick with: Select,Delete,Read,Update,Insert,CreateIndex,DropIndex,AlterTable,CreateTable,DropTable,CreateTempTable,DropTempTable